# Elasticsearch 7 number_format_exception for input value as a String

Tags: elasticsearch, search, keyword-search

I have field in index with mapping as :

```
 "sequence_number" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "copy_to" : [
            "_custom_all"
          ]
        }
```

and using search query as

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "sequence_number": {
        "value": "we"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting error message :

```
,"index_uuid":"FTAW8qoYTPeTj-cbC5iTRw","index":"my_index","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"we\""}}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:260) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:238) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1433) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
        at
```

How can i ignore number_format_exception errors, so the query just doesn't return anything or ignores this filter in particular - either is acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Elasticsearch Ninja, Thanks for reply, I am validating query using ES Validate api before execution now. That will help me to find out invalid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible, ideally, you should have [coherce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) enabled on your numeric fields so that your index doesn't contain dirty data.

The best solution is that in your application which generated the Elasticsearch query(you should have a check for `NumberFormatExcepton` if you are searching for numeric fields as your index doesn't contain the dirty data in the first place and reject the query if you get an exception in your application).

**Edit:** Another interesting approach is to validate the data before inserting into ES, using the [Validate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) as suggested by @prakash, only thing is that it would add another network call but if your application is not latency-sensitive, it can be used as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am validating query using ES Validate api before execution now. That will help me to find out invalid query and return empty response if query is invalid.

Comment: @prakash.panjwani yeah but that will cause latency (as you are making another roundtrip), but if you don't have latency issue, I guess this sounds reasonable :)

Comment: @prakash.panjwani, looking forward to get your feedback on the latency.. and your configuration(no of ES nodes, cluster, QPS, shards, replica  etc)

Comment: We are not facing latency issue till now. Thanks